# Coloring and filling a list plot

Tags: plotting, color, filling

I'm trying to make it so that the color of the dot at the top is the color of the vertical line that goes down to the axis.

```
f[x_] := Last[FixedPointList[# - Sin[#]/Cos[#] &, x]]/π;
start = 1;
stop = 2.2;
steps = 1200;
window = 1.1;
stepsize = N[(stop - start)/steps];
range = Range[start, stop, stepsize];
p1 = 
  ListPlot[
    Table[Style[Sin[t], Hue[f[t]/(10 π)]], {t, start, stop, stepsize}], 
    PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium], 
    PlotRange -> Automatic, 
    Filling -> Axis];
Show[p1, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

But it just fills it with blue. I also can not figure out how to make the bottom axis the range instead of the natural numbers, but that's less important right now.

Comment: `Last[FixedPointList[# - Sin[#]/Cos[#] &, x]]/π` can be shortened to `FixedPoint[# - Sin[#]/Cos[#] &, x]/π`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why you use `ListPlot` with a table instead of calling `Plot` with a color function:

```
Plot[Sin[t], {t, start, stop}, ColorFunction -> (Hue[f[#]/(10 Pi)] &),
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Filling -> Axis, 
  PlotPoints -> 1200, MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Probably because im still fumbling my way thew this programing thing. 

Thank you so much! I spent so much time looking things up in the references and you solved it in just seconds, im in awe!

Comment: @Wombles When you want to have the same resolution as in your `ListPlot`, you should use the options `PlotPoints -> 1200, MaxRecursion -> 0` in `Plot`.

Answer (score 2):

You are computing so many tightly packed values of `Sin` in your table that it makes no sense to make a list plot with filling. The plot elements are like a bunch of lollypops being scrunched too close together. It is better to forget about the pops at end the sticks and just draw the sticks. This is easily done with `Graphics`.

```
f[x_] := Last[FixedPointList[# - Sin[#]/Cos[#] &, x]]/π
Module[{start, stop, steps, domain, lines},
  start = 1.;
  stop = 2.2;
  steps = 500;
  domain = Subdivide[start, stop, steps];
  lines = Table[{Hue[f[t]/(10 π)], Line @ {{t, .8}, {t, Sin[t]}}}, {t, domain}];
  Graphics[lines, Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, ImageSize -> 450]]
```

This gives

[image: graphics]

which is very much like the plot halirutan shows in his answer.

#### Update

This is attempt to address an issue raised by halirutan in some comments he made.

Yes, I see there are color artifacts being created -- some kind of color moire pattern is showing up because even reducing the number of lines to 500 from the OP's 1200 is packing too many lines into the rendered image at the size specified.

The artifacts can be reduced if not entirely eliminated by making a better choice of both the number lines and their thickness. Here is what I think is such better choice.

```
Module[{start, stop, steps, domain, lines},
  start = 1.;
  stop = 2.2;
  steps = 280;
  domain = Subdivide[start, stop, steps];
  lines = Table[{Hue[f[t]/(10 π)], Line @ {{t, .8}, {t, Sin[t]}}}, {t, domain}];
  Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[2], lines},
    Axes -> True,
    AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
    ImageSize -> 450]]
```

[image: graphics]

Clearly Mathematica's filling algorithm is more sophisticated than just drawing lines as I did. That certainly makes using `Plot` with `Fill` a better approach than mine.

Comment: I'm not sure why this happens, but there shouldn't be any color variations in the range `[0, 0.8]`. Look at `Table[f[x]/(10 Pi), {x, 0, .8, .0001}] //DeleteDuplicates`. Do you know why your colors *wobble* in those constant regions?

Comment: @halirutan. I don't understand what you are asking. The domain extent [0, .8] doesn't appear in my plot. I am plotting over [1., 2.2].

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is the regions that should be uniformly colored. I have updated the image in my post. See the region [2.0, 2.2]. It's completely one color while in your image there are variations. I wondered why that is. Checking this region shows one value for `f`: `Table[f[x]/(10 Pi), {x, 2, 2.2, .0001}] // DeleteDuplicates`

Comment: After trying your code I see that it is a rendering artifact that comes from using `Line`. If you resize your graphics, you see how the color shows aliasing artifacts that shift.

Comment: @halirutan. I have made an update which attempts to address the issue you are raising.